# Can we alter a form using view data?

Tags: views, forms, hooks

I is possible to:

1. Hook on `views_pre_view` (which is executed before `form_alter`)
2. Query `view data` (execute the view query filtering according to URL parameters) and collect some data
3. Hook on `form_alter`
4. Replace some selects using data collected on item 2?

I'm asking because if I `$view->execute()` inside `views_pre_view` (to filter and use view data) it will internally call `form_alter` and generate the form before I'm able to collect the data to pre-populate my selects. And I'm not sure if it's possible to re-generate a form that was already generated.

I also tried `views_pre_execute` but this one is always executed after `form_alter`.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, may you be so kind to rephrase your question? I am unsure about which is the final goal of this task. Are you willing to, given a view result, modify a form and insert some data from the view? Are you willing to modify exposed filters? Is something different? I don't fully understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found for now was to, inside `views_pre_view`, deep clone the `$view` object using `$view = unserialize(serialize($_view))`, so when Drupal passes again on `form_alter` the form would be untouched and I can just recreate some selects.